# Extending CakeDC users plugin for use with Opauth or OpenID

Tags: php, cakephp, oauth, openid, cakedc

I am currently in the process of trying to extend the cakeDC users plugin.  It is proving relatively difficult to integrate this plugin with the plugin for Opauth located here:

https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-opauth

For instance I want in my application the ability to register and login a user via facebook, google etc...

I have been attempting this with the google implementation and I am able to retrieve data back from Google through the opauth plugin.  My issues lies with what do I do with this information now?  If I want to register this user with my App, I don't know the next steps to do this...

This is what the data returned in the array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [auth] => Array
        (
            [uid] => 1xxxxxxxxx1
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [name] => xxx xxx
                    [email] => xx.xx@xx.com
                    [first_name] => xx
                    [last_name] => xx
                )

            [credentials] => Array
                (
                    [token] => #%*(&)(*&%)*^$^)($%
                    [expires] => 2013-08-09T19:23:10+00:00
                )

            [raw] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1XXXXXXXXXXXXX1
                    [email] => XXXX.XXXXX@XXXXX.com
                    [verified_email] => 1
                    [name] => XXX XXX
                    [given_name] => XXXX
                    [family_name] => XXXXX
                    [gender] => male
                    [locale] => en
                    [hd] => test.com
                )

            [provider] => Google
        )

    [timestamp] => 2013-08-09T18:23:11+00:00
    [signature] => *#&$&$$&$&$&$&$$####
    [validated] => 1
)
```

It doesnt seem to me that there is a password token that stays generated to compare with but that isnt even the current blocker.  The blocker resides in how to register this information into the cakeDC users plugin extended class.  Any help is greatly appreciated, and I am sure I am not the only developer out there curious how to extend this pluging to be integrated with the Opauth plugin.

EDITS:    (** WORKING LOGIN CODE **)

```
        public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->Allow('opauth_complete');

}
public function opauth_complete() {

    $user = $this->set('opauth_data', $this->request->data);

    $loginUser = $this->User->find('first', 
        array('fields'=>array('User.*'), 
            'conditions'=>array('User.email'=>$this->request->data['auth']['info']['email'])));

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login($loginUser)) {

           //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
           $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are logged in.'));

        }else{

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are currently not Authorized'));

        }

    }

}
```

The hangup seems to be on $this->Auth->login($loginUser);  It find the user in the database, and yet it still wont authorize them through the google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty clear what needs to be done with this remote data:

1. Save it to your DB if it does not already exist, generate some artificial password, just     use the id and some secret salt for example
2. Log the user with this data in using $this->Auth->login($data);

If you want to allow an existing user to associate the remote account with the local account you'll have to implement the logic and workflow for that. Save the opauth data to the session, redirect to a registration / login form and let the user enter his username and password and then associate the remote account by using the with this user.

Comment: I've looked at this over and over and seem to be missing a step, and probably a minor one.  I have edited my initial question and you will see my very basic attempt to authorize registered user

Comment: Turns out this was the key all along:

 public function beforeFilter() {

  $this->Auth->Allow('opauth_complete');

 }